# backup heavy website in PHP getting timeout

Tags: php, backup

I am trying to take heavy files backup with PHP but for more then 1 GB files I am getting PHP timeout error how I can resolve this please help me with complete code. below is my complete code.
please check my code and suggest code change that can help me. I have tried number of code and functions but nothing happen. I am very frustrated for this task

```
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000000);
@ini_set('memory_limit', '10000M');


function zipData($source, $destination, $ignores = [])
{
    if (extension_loaded('zip') === true) {
        if (file_exists($source) === true) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();

            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) {
                $source = realpath($source);

                if (is_dir($source) === true) {
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        $file = realpath($file);

                        $ignored = false;

                        foreach ($ignores as $ignore) {
                            if (strpos($file, $ignore)) {
                                $ignored = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ($ignored) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (is_dir($file) === true) {
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                        } else if (is_file($file) === true) {
                            // $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                            $zip->addFile($file, str_replace($source . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $file));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (is_file($source) === true) {
                    //$zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                    $zip->addFile($source, basename($source));
                }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}


$backup_path = 'create_backup_site/site_backup_' . date('Y-m-d');
if (!file_exists($backup_path)) {
    mkdir($backup_path, 0777, true);
}

$name_zip_file = $backup_path . '/' . date("j-n-Y") . '-backup.zip';

$ignorearray = array('create_backup');

$dir = '../../test/wp-content/uploads';


function listFolderFiles($dir, $backup_path)
{
    $fileInfo     = scandir($dir);
    $allFileLists = [];
    $allpathname = [];

    foreach ($fileInfo as $folder) {
        if ($folder !== '.' && $folder !== '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder) === true) {
                $allFileLists[$folder] = listFolderFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder, $backup_path);
                //$allFileLists[$folder]['file_path'] = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder;
                $allpathname[] = listFolderFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder, $backup_path);
            } else {
                $filesize = filesize($dir . '/' . $folder);
                // if ($filesize < 1073741824) {
               // if ($filesize < 536870912) {  //512 mb size check
                if ($filesize < 1048576) {  //512 mb size check
                    $allFileLists[$folder] = array("file_name" => $folder, "file_path" => $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
                    $allpathname[] = $folder;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $allFileLists;

$dirlist = listFolderFiles($dir, $backup_path);

$final_array = array();
$final_array_path = array();
foreach ($dirlist as $key => $value) {


    if (is_array($value)) {

        foreach ($value as $newkey => $newvalue) {
            
            foreach ($newvalue as $key2 => $val2) {
                
                if ($val2['file_name'] != '.') {
                    if (strlen($val2['file_name']) > 2) {
                        $final_array[] = array('file_name' => $val2['file_name'], 'file_path' => $val2['file_path']);
                        $filepatrh = str_replace($val2['file_name'],"",$val2['file_path']);
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($newvalue['file_name'] != '.') {
                if (strlen($newvalue['file_name']) > 2) {
                    $final_array[] = array('file_name' => $newvalue['file_name'], 'file_path' => $newvalue['file_path']);
                    $filepatrh = str_replace($newvalue['file_name'],"",$newvalue['file_path']);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    } else {

    }
    if ($value['file_name'] != '.') {
        if (strlen($value['file_name']) > 2) {
            $final_array[] = array('file_name' => $value['file_name'], 'file_path' => $value['file_path']);
            $filepatrh = str_replace($value['file_name'],"",$value['file_path']);
            
        }
    }
}

foreach ($final_array as $final_key => $final_value) {
    zipData($final_value['file_path'], $backup_path . '/uploads.zip', $ignorearray);
    echo 'Finished.';
}

}
```

Comment: Are you running this from a web process or a CLI process?

Comment: You may find it convenient to do large full-folder backups NOT using PHP. `tar -pczf /path/to/backups/backup.tar.gz /path/to/directory/to/backup` would be heaps easier.

Comment: @ChrisHaas running web process

Comment: @MarkusAO i want to do this via PHP

Comment: If you really want to do this in PHP, I would break this into several parts. One would be a PHP CLI script that does most of your current script. Another would be a PHP script that submits requests to a queue (database, file, etc.) requesting that the backup be run. The last would be a script that monitors the status of the backup

Comment: @ChrisHaas 
can you explain me with the help of code or complete code via which i can do backup heavy files in php